# How to escape the > sign on Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt

For example, `foo -option 10->30 file.ext` (this is an actual syntax required) redirects the output to a file named 30. How do I make cmd understand that I would like to pass the actual > character? I've tried several forms of double quotes to no avail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cmd escape character is `^` so:

```
foo -option 10-^>30 file.ext
```

should work for you

Comment: I never would have known/guessed that - I still can't believe that someone is writing windows software the requires a reserved character.

Comment: @mfinni: I often use the caret as escape in a FOR loop containing pipe(s).  Long live batch! :)

Comment: @jscott - lets not start that craziness :) Powershell to the rescue.

Comment: @mfinni: It's perfectly normal in most other places (such as Linuxland).

Comment: @grawity - that's why I specified "windows software". I know that when you're doing stuff in shell/batch or via pipes or other weird-ish environments, even in windows, you have to escape a lot of things. But he just said he's using cmd - I never would have thought someone would purposefully write something that guaranteed wouldn't work from cmd.

Comment: @mfinni But it does. You just need to escape it as usual.

Comment: @grawity It's a tool ported from Linuxland, so they may not be aware of other operating systems' limitations... or aware, but not particularly interested in accommodating Windows users.

Answer (score 1):

You can also quote the argument:

```
foo -option "10->30" file.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask the vendor for the `foo` command how it's supposed to work?

Comment: −1. That's the shell and not the program doing something with the `>` here.

Comment: I understand that - I simply don't see a competent vendor writing software for windows with syntax that *won't work out of the box* on the default shell. Not sure the -1 is necessary.